# Apache Dedicated Server Crashing

Tags: php, server, crash, dedicated-server

We have a Wordpress site hosted on an Apache dedicated server on Fasthosts. We don't know whether it's a coincidence or not but these crashes have been happening since we installed an SSL Certificate on the website. Fasthosts themselves cannot provide support for this so we're reaching out here to see if someone can help.

The server crashes around 8 times a day and it seems to be PHP related. Please find the crash report we receive each time the server crashes here:

https://pastebin.com/id2NF9D0

```
Please see Pastebin here.
```

We don't really understand the error log here but if someone does and could point us in the right direction to perhaps fixing this that would be most helpful.

If any further information is needed please just reply and ask.

Regards,

Lewis

Comment: Your PHP version was end-of-lifed about three years ago, and doesn't meet WP's current minimum requirement. It's probably not worth your time to debug it.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Which PHP is the server using from reading the error log? Are you suggesting to upgrade the PHP version on the server? According to the server it's using 5.3.3 by OS Vendor and running PHP as FastCGI application served by Apache. This is using Plesk Dashboard.

Comment: The log refers to v5.3.3. _"Are you suggesting to upgrade"_ Absolutely. v5.3 isn't getting security fixes anymore and you can't run the current version of WP on 5.3, which means you're probably not getting WP security fixes either.